# Incompatible types on extended class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a netbeans desktop java project which has been working flawlessly.  I decided to duplicate the generated `AboutBox` to mess around with it.  I copied the .java file inside my project's package, then pasted a copy into the package.  I didn't do a refactor copy.

Immediately, my project view lit up all red with an error.  I clicked into it, and suddenly this code was throwing an error:

```
@Action
    public void showAboutBox() {
        if (aboutBox == null) {
            JFrame mainFrame = ProjectApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
            aboutBox = new ProjectAboutBox(mainFrame); //this is the line throwing the error
            aboutBox.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
        }
        ProjectApp.getApplication().show(aboutBox);
    }
```

The error read:

> Incompatible types, javax.Swing.JDialog expected, found:
>   project.ProjectAboutBox.

Naturally, I deleted the copy of the about box as a first step, but the error persisted.  I changed nothing in either the main project or the about box, just pasted an extra .java file in, and suddenly the whole thing broke.  What the heck happened?

And, in case anyone asks, I did check that the class was in fact a `JDialog`:

```
public class ProjectAboutBox extends javax.swing.JDialog {//etc}
```

Comment: " I didn't do a refactor copy. " Do a refactor copy

Comment: If you have not tried yet do `Project`->`Clean`

Comment: How is `aboutBox` declared?

Comment: @EvcanMustafa That doesn't solve the problem, since the copy doesn't even exist anymore.  Can you explain how making a non-refactor copy causes a reference to the original to suddenly break?

Comment: @PM77-1 Cleaned, to no avail.  Also, to answer your other question: `private JDialog aboutBox;`  Again, I didn't change that when I pasted the copy.

Comment: You'll want to instantiate it as `private ProjectAboutBox aboutBox` to see if that works. Java *should* pick up the inheritance, but this will be proof that the rest of your code is not at fault.